# C Program hangs after trying to call function from main

Tags: c, function, call, freeze

This is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "descartes.h"

/*
 *  Eulidean travelling salesman
 */

#define MAXCITIES 100
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

point_t city [MAXCITIES];
int numCities = 0;

int ReadCities(void);
double TourLength(lineSeg_t cityLines[]);
void DrawTour(void);

int main(void) {
  printf ("main1\n");    
  OpenGraphics();    
  printf ("main2\n");
  ReadCities();    
  DrawTour();    
  double TourLength(lineSeg_t cityLines[]);    
  CloseGraphics();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


int ReadCities(void) {
  printf ("ReadCities1");
  int i = 1;

  printf ("ReadCities2");

  city[0] = GetPoint();
  while ((XCoord(city[i])) >= 0) {
    city[i] = GetPoint();
    printf ("(%d, %d)", XCoord(city[i]), YCoord(city[i]));
    numCities++;
    i++;
  }

  if (numCities <= MAXCITIES) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}


double TourLength(lineSeg_t cityLines[]) {
  double totLen = 0;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < (numCities - 1); i++) {
    totLen += Length(cityLines[i]);
  }

  return totLen;
}


void DrawTour(void) {
  lineSeg_t cityLines[MAXCITIES];
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < (numCities - 1); i++) {
    cityLines[i] = LineSeg(city[i], city[i + 1]);
    DrawLineSeg(cityLines[i]);
  }
}
```

When I run the program it prints:

```
main1
main2
```

Then the program hangs. I would at least expect it to call `ReadCities()` and at  get as far as printing

```
ReadCities1
ReadCities2
```

but no matter what I try it just hangs with a flashing cursor in the terminal after printing `main2`. There might also be other mistakes in the code but I can't even get far enough to test it out!

Sorry if it's something obvious, i'm new to programming!
Cheers!

Comment: You mind creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Half of the functions which are called are not defined here, anyway.

Comment: MCVE? ill do my best to help you help me :P @SouravG

Comment: Use a debugger. At the minimum it will tell you where the code is "stuck".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why there is a function prototype inside `main`?

Comment: Yes ill do that now and update the question post @martin

Comment: And add "\n" to the end of your debug `printf` strings. `printf` is line buffered so there will be no output until a newline or an explicit flush. Which makes it confusing during debugging (especially for beginners) as it may appear a section of code was not executed even though it was (the `printf` just didn't get flushed).

Comment: Add `\n` after the ReadCities1 and ReadCities2 strings so the output buffer gets flushed to the terminal.

Comment: @Eugene 'OpenGraphics();' is a function used in the '"descartes.h"' lib and dosent need to be defined, this I know from previous use

Comment: The function prototype I am talking about is `TourLength`.  And it is not used there.

Comment: @keith I think that was it! I got the printouts "ReadCities1" and "ReadCities2". I think Ill give it another shot of debugging now that I know it is actually calling the function, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what this line:

```
while ((XCoord(city[i])) >= 0)
```

Is returning, seems this loop might not be breaking. In a situation like this I'd printf() the value ofo XCoord(city[i]) within my loop to see what value is actually in there...

Using printf()'s can be quite useful for things like this.

Also, as someone said there's a function prototype declaration in main:

double TourLength(lineSeg_t cityLines[]);

Comment: Ok, ill try those things!

Comment: When i change `double TourLength(lineSeg_t cityLines[]);` to `TourLength(lineSeg_t cityLines[]);` i get the error `expected expression before ‘lineSeg_t’
   TourLength(lineSeg_t cityLines[]);`. whats the reason for this, cheers

Comment: Well you're still declaring the types to be passed. lineSeg_t cityLines[] is a declaration...you're not declaring the functiopn here you should be calling it...essentially you should be passing an array of type lineSeg_t to the function.

Comment: lineSeg_t myArray[n]; << you'd declare your array like this - the prototype should be in the global scope (above main) and you'd call the function and pass the array of the declared type like TourLength(&myArray[0]);

Comment: Well....you'd need to declare it. Your function prototype doesn't declare any memory it just specifies what parameters a function accepts. You need to declare cityLines[] array in your main.

Comment: To be honest it's pretty difficult to really help you here, being a small comments section. You seem to have some confusion over function prototypes, I suggest you back up a bit and start over. You declare a function protype that states "this function accepts an array of this type" then you declare the array of that type and pass it to the function when you call it.